# how to use Django template if condition inside Django Template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

```
{% if len(verifiedJobs) > 0 %}
{% for v in verifiedJobs %}
companyname:::{{v.companyname}}<br>
jobDescription::::{{v.jobDescription}}<br>
salary:::{{v.salary}}<br>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

this is my code and it is not working it is giving errors about my if condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django templates don't understand the length function so that's why its giving you an error.
suppose the length of  verifiedjob is 0 it will be considered as false and the if condition will not work and if its value is anything different than 0 it will work

```
{% if verifiedJobs %}
{% for v in verifiedJobs %}
companyname:::{{v.companyname}}<br>
jobDescription:::{{v.jobDescription}}<br>
salary:::{{v.salary}}<br>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```